# Magento 2.4.3 - Green and red light for in stock and out of stock

Tags: magento2.4.3, stock-status

A bit weird question that I got from my client.

Is there a way to make a green "light" or "dot" just next to where it says in stock and a red one for where it says out of the stock front end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done by CSS

```
.stock.available::after {
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: green;
    display: inline-block;
    content: open-quote;
}
```

[image]

Same can be done for non available stock

Comment: Thanks for this, the greenlight worked. However, the problem is they have allowed backorder on this website. So the stock is never unavailable. Is there a way to use CSS that will recognize when the stock is 0?

Comment: for that we need to add logic in phtml/block class and need to check qty and and add class if qty is zero.